# Can I run an Arduino Nano with 12V for this VU meter project?

Tags: arduino

Here is my project diagram:

[image: Diagram]

Here they use a 5 volt LED but I have a 12V LED. That's why I want to use a 12V power supply. Can I use it?

Comment: LEDs should not be fed through MCU  .They consume big current.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, the Nano takes a 5V power supply.  12V will kill it in an instant.  If you have a 12V supply you will need to use a voltage regulator or other voltage converter to get 5V to supply the Nano.

Keep in mind that the Nano's input/output pins are NOT 12V tolerant. So you will need to ensure that you keep all voltages that the pins are exposed to at 0-5V.

A circuit similar to this will get you 5V from a 12V source although there are many other possibilities.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2firsJv.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: but where i have to add that voltage regulator please tell me

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Only the LED strips and the power input to the Arduino (\$\text V_{IN}\$) see the 12V. Suggest adding a resistor on the D6 output. Of course the LED strips must be the programmable WS2812 type (or compatible) for it to work.

The pots and switch connect to the 5V output from the on-board regulator AMS1117 of the Nano (+5V pin).

Do not use automotive 12V directly, only a regulated 12V adapter or similar.

Comment: if i add register in d6 then how i safe my nano from 12v?

Comment: Safe-er not safe. An example of the sort of thing that might cause disaster would be a loose ground wire on one of the LED strips. To make it completely safe would probably require too high a resistance for it to work properly.

Comment: @user263983  The strips are not just the WS2812. There are [many strips](https://www.amazon.com/ALITOVE-Addressable-Programmable-Waterproof-Raspberry/dp/B07L3QD1LF) which operate from 12V and have WS2812 chips. That is what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @user263983 The [WS2813 datasheet](http://www.normandled.com/upload/201605/WS2813%20LED%20Datasheet.pdf)  says +5.3V absolute max.

Comment: Showing seller page is not sufficient information. WS2812 on title only to bring an attention. WS2815 fed 12V. What OP has only OP knows?

Comment: @user263983 If it is 12V (as stated) it must be WS2812 compatible. Anything with a TTL-level data input should not damage the Arduino, but it might not work.

Comment: WS2815 has nominal voltage 12V and not compatible with WS2812. Data is Vdd-0.5/Vcc+0.5V.

Comment: @user263983 You are confusing Vdd and Vcc. On the WS2815 the valid logic levels are Vcc * 0.3/0.7, which is normal CMOS levels. Vcc is 5V nominal  (+/-10%) and is generated on chip. Vdd is 9.5 to 13.5V.

Comment: P.S. Vdd-0.5V  on the datasheet is obviously an error. It should say GND-0.5V (or Vss-0.5V) for the lower absolute maximum input voltage limit.

Comment: OK.  I found original datasheet from Worldsemi. You right.

Comment: @user263983 Ah, WS = WorldSemi, easy to remember. The factory datasheet is only available in Chinese it appears. The English link downloads a .jpg of the part.

Comment: https://www.alldatasheet.net/datasheet-pdf/pdf/1134588/WORLDSEMI/WS2815B.html here is English

Comment: http://www.world-semi.com/Certifications/details-138-4.html  The manufacturer's webpage though does not have it.